# Excel-VBA: to copy column value from one workbook to another

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub copy()
    Dim x As Workbook
    Dim y As Workbook
    Set x = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Saurabh\Desktop\Book2.xls")
    Set y = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Saurabh\Desktop\Book1.xls")
    x.Sheets("sheet1").Range("G2").Value = x.Sheets("sheet1").Range("A2").Value
    y.Sheets("sheet1").Range("H2").Value = x.Sheets("sheet1").Range("B2").Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Its not working out for me. Its compile but it don't show any value in other sheet or same sheet

Comment: as for me your code works fine, maybe problem is in logic?. I see that you **copy `[A2]` to `[G2]` inside `X`** workbook, but the second line transfer value from `[B2]` of `X` to `[H2]` of `Y` workbook

Comment: yes I need to copy a column within a given sheet and also to another workbook.

Comment: so you need copy **'column'** instead of value of the particular cell as in your code?

Comment: Yes. but its not working out so I tried to copy one value

Answer (score 1):

works fine in my machine, try it

```
Sub copy()
    Dim x As Workbook
    Dim y As Workbook
    Set x = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Saurabh\Desktop\Book2.xls")
    Set y = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Saurabh\Desktop\Book1.xls")
    x.Sheets("sheet1").[A:A].copy x.Sheets("sheet1").[G:G] 'copy column from x [A:A] to x [G:G]
    x.Sheets("sheet1").[B:B].copy y.Sheets("sheet1").[H:H] 'copy column from x [B:B] to y [H:H]
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

just fix that

From

```
   x.Sheets("sheet1").Range("G2").Value = x.Sheets("sheet1").Range("A2").Value
   y.Sheets("sheet1").Range("H2").Value = x.Sheets("sheet1").Range("B2").Value
```

To

```
x.Sheets("sheet1").Range("G2").Value = y.Sheets("sheet1").Range("A2").Value
x.Sheets("sheet1").Range("H2").Value = x.Sheets("sheet1").Range("B2").Value
```

Comment: This method I can't use because if this work I need to add a for loop on this and then add more column and restrict the column to add value till specific value come in column.

Comment: But, I can give a try and let u know. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Below code copies the cells fine

```
Sub copy()
    Dim x As Workbook
    Dim y As Workbook
    Set x = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\user\Desktop\Book2.xlsx")
    Set y = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\user\Desktop\Book1.xlsx")
    x.Sheets("sheet1").Range("G2").Value = y.Sheets("sheet1").Range("A2").Value
    x.Sheets("sheet1").Range("H2").Value = y.Sheets("sheet1").Range("B2").Value
End Sub
```

Comment: but this is the same code as OP provided, but you did replacement of the `x` to `y`, why?)

Comment: the x and y were incorrectly mentioned and hence blanks were getting copied and hence OP thought that the script was not working.

Comment: OP code works fine, but I guess OP has two problems, first is that required to copy columns instead of values of the cell, and the second probably that handled wrong logic with `x.[G2] = x.[A2] and x.[H2] = y.[B2]`, so I agree with `@Omar` post that OP may need this `x.[A2] = x.[G2] and y.[B2] = x.[H2]`

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty sure you need to capitalize your "s" in "sheet1", so it's properly "**S**heet1". I believe it's case-sensitive.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried that out. Sheet1. But still its not doing anything. The code and path are correct. I tried it but till it show no output.